# Exchange 2013 NDR issue for not existed user in a mailing list

Tags: exchange-server-2013

I have an Exchange 2013 server.
Faced with a strange issue of email delivery what I can not solve.
Exchange is rejecting email
if one of the recipients is not exist in a domain 
Email will be rejected totally and sender will receive NDR for not existing user.

```
scenario:
Exchange mailboxes user@domain.com  // valid user
user1@domain.com  //**user mailbox is not exist**
Sending email from external domain to my exchange server:
TO: user@domain.com,user1@domain.com
Reciving NDR Remote Server returned '550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound;
valid user didn't receive email also.
email is rejected
```

.

I start to google and found that [How do I reject incoming email for unknown users in MS Exchange 2013?](https://support.prolateral.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/204/35/how-do-i-reject-incoming-email-for-unknown-users-in-ms-exchange-2013)
exchange has a user validation feature that is enabled by default
I disable it on a console restart transport role.
Set-RecipientFilterConfig -RecipientValidationEnabled $false

run the same scenario again
user@domain.com, user1.domain.com
I receive NDR for not existing user.
but email was delivered to valid user.
Is it a normal behavior for exchange?
What is right by RFC deliver for valid users or reject email?
how it will affect our server hit the public spam list?
Does this not reduce our spam filter resistance?

Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for Exchange to send an NDR for non existing users. As you already said, this might also trigger some spam lists because you are sending out mails (NDR) to possible spam honey pots.

A better way to do this would be to have your external MTA (the server which accepts the mail from the internet) check the recipients and refuse to accept mail for non existent email addresses. This way you would never have to send out NDR reports, as the server trying to deliver mail would be informed that it cannot deliver and notifies the sender itself.